# CodedUI test script not executing from virtual machine windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, coded-ui-tests

I am using Windows 7 in vmware fusion on my mac.

I am using vs 2012 in Win7 VM and am able to record scripts.

When I try to execute it doesnot reply. (write click on test method -> Run or from Test Explorer).

It used to work perfectly find on Win7VM on Windows host, but facing issue on vm hosted in Mac.

Is anyone facing similar issue. Any Solution ?

Answer (score 0):

We manage to run the codedUI test cases in windows hyper-V with window 7 and 8 VMs it works fine. I never tried it in mac but you may try to run in minimized mode by and giving the active screen to virtual machine or login to your VM from another pc and try. This [Link](http://binaryclips.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/coded-ui-tests-executing-a-test-case-while-desktop-is-not-active/) will help with that approach.